# Has Facebook authentication behaviour for Windows Store Apps changed?

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, windows-8.1, facebook-access-token

I noticed some change in Facebook's authentication behaviour recently: when authenticating via the Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker, I now get a short-lived token back from Facebook to my app, instead of the long-lived token I got before.

I can see this behaviour both if I login directly or whether I am utilizing SSO (http://facebooksdk.net/docs/windows/sso/).

When debugging the token, Facebook indicates that the origin for the login request is coming from the Web. Accordingly, Facebook is returning short-lived tokens.

It is quite easy to exchange the short-lived token with a long-lived token and I could do that (http://facebooksdk.net/docs/web/handling-expired-access-tokens/). However, this requires that I am transmitting the app secret id, which I'd prefer not to from an app.

Can anyone confirm that Facebook has done such a change? And the bonus question ;-): is there a way to still get long-lived tokens from Windows Store Apps without transmitting the app secret?

Thanks,
Andreas

--Update April 11:

I might have stumbled across an explanation why/when this change was introduced: WebAuthenticationBroker now includes some methods that enable silent authentication; I guess that happened when Microsoft introduced the Windows 8.1 Update 1 last week. Together with SSO silent authentication should do the trick, but I still need to verify...

Comment: Just want to ask, why exactly you want to extend the token?

Comment: Because it's not really user friendly when the user has to repeat the same login/authorization step every day.

Comment: What actions are you performing in your app using the facebook graph api?

Comment: None. I am just getting items from the user's Facebook stream via FQL.

Comment: But for the sake of the discussion, you could safely assume that the app acts as a Facebook client for Win 8. Honestly, I don't know any Facebook clients that require users to reauthenticate after 1 hour. And if I did, I would not use them ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't use this library, but it doesn't seems possible to me that you were able to get the long-lived token from it; since there is no other way to get the extended token without using the `app-secret`.

If you have a server configured, you can create a small API for this and get the extended token from your server.

Comment: Yes, getting short-lived tokens is somehow consistent with the description of both the SDK and WebAuthenticationBroker. Still until recent, the overall behaviour was different. Therefore, I wanted to know whether more people witnessed that change.

In the best case, I could then figure out more clearly where the change happened (on the Facebook or on the Microsoft side) - and potentially what alternative solutions there are after that change. And yes, setting up a server is definitely one of those alternatives, but definitely not my preferred one.